# NLA - Repeating an action progressively

Tags: animation, dopesheet, nla-editor

I know the title isn't very descriptive, but that's because I can't describe it better in short.

I'm having fun using the NLA editor, but I've run into a problem I'd really like to solve automatically, not manually.

Let's say I have an object that has a short action:
[image: cube action]

Now, if I put this action into a track in the NLA editor and turn up the repeat number, the cube will obviously snap back to the beginning. What I'd like is for the cube to start the animation where it left off. See image:

[image: repeated action]

Is there a way to do this without keying each cycle manually? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could more easily do it through the *Graph Editor*: open the *Graph Editor*, select the track that you want to repeat indifinitely, for example the *X Location* track, open the right panel with <kbd>N</kbd>, add a *Cycles* modifier and in the *After* dropdown menu choose the *Repeat with Offset* otion. Do the same operation for the *Y Location* track as your object move on both these axis.

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Perfect solution, thanks :)